# Get index of RootNodes

Tags: c#, uwp, treeview

In [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view), the index is `0`. My code has more than one root. How to get the index of the selected root?

```
 private void TreeView_DragItemsCompleted(TreeView sender, TreeViewDragItemsCompletedEventArgs args)
 {
            var children = sourceTreeView.RootNodes[0].Children;

            if (deletedItem != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (children[i].Content.ToString() == deletedItem.Content.ToString())
                    {
                        children.RemoveAt(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            sourceTreeView = null;
            deletedItem = null;
 }
```

Comment: Does the following works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get index of RootNodes

Please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56786192/7254781). You could create bind-able data source like the case reply. And bind the `IsSelected` property for `TreeViewItem`. When item selected `IsSelected` value will be changed, so you could foreach the itemsource then get the index of selected item.

```
<TreeViewItem 
    AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Name}"
    IsExpanded="{x:Bind IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsSelected="{x:Bind IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}"
    >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="20" Source="../Assets/folder.png" />
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</TreeViewItem>
```

**Get index**

```
 private int GetIndex(ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem> DataSource)
 {
     int index = 0;
     foreach (var item in DataSource)
     {
         if (item.IsSelected == true)
         {
             index = DataSource.IndexOf(item);                 
         }
     }
     return index;
 }
```